# hide image with animate package

Tags: tikz-pgf, rotating, animate

I am rotating a triangle, I want only the first and last triangle of the last two frames to appear.

I want the triangles that are between the first and last triangle to be hidden.

Attached latex code.

```
    \documentclass[12pt]{article}
    \usepackage{animate}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{pgf,tikz}
    \usepackage{color}

\begin{filecontents}{time.txt}
    ::0x0 
    ::1 
    ::2
    ::3
\end{filecontents}    

    \begin{document}

    \begin{center}

    \begin{animateinline}[
    begin={
    \begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm]
    \clip(-4.7,-3.7)  rectangle (4.7,3.7);
    },
    end={\end{tikzpicture}},
    controls,timeline=time.txt]{1}

    \draw [color=gray] (-4.5,-3.2) grid (4.5,3.2);

    \foreach \x in {-4,...,4}
    \draw [very thick] (\x,0.1) -- (\x,-0.1) node[below] {\x};
    \foreach \y in {-3,...,3}
    \draw [very thick] (0.1,\y) -- (-0.1,\y) node[left] {\y};

    \draw [<->, very thick] (-4.5,0) -- (4.5,0) node [below] {$x$};
    \draw [<->, very thick] (0,-3.5) -- (0,3.5) node [right] {$y$};

    \draw [line width=1.5pt] (0,1) -- (1,3) -- (3,1) -- cycle;

    \newframe % GIRO 90°

    \draw [color=blue,line width=1.5pt] (-1,0) -- (-3,1) -- (-1,3)-- cycle;

    \draw[color=black] (3.,2.7) node[anchor=north west] {\colorbox{white}{$\alpha=90$}};
    \draw [->,line width=1.5pt](0.5,0) arc (0:90:0.5cm);

    \newframe % GIRO 180°

    \draw [color=blue,line width=1.5pt] (0,-1) -- (-1,-3) -- (-3,-1)-- cycle;

    \draw[color=black] (3.,2.7) node[anchor=north west] {\colorbox{white}{$\alpha=180$}};
    \draw [->,line width=1.5pt](0.5,0) arc (0:180:0.5cm);

    \newframe % GIRO 270°

    \draw [color=blue, line width=1.5pt] (1,0) -- (3,-1) -- (1,-3)-- cycle;

    \draw[color=black] (3.,2.7) node[anchor=north west] {\colorbox{white}{$\alpha=270$}};
    \draw [->,line width=1.5pt](0.5,0) arc (0:270:0.5cm);

    \newframe % GIRO 360°

    \draw [color=blue,line width=1.5pt] (0,1) -- (1,3) -- (3,1)-- cycle;

    \draw[color=black] (3.,2.7) node[anchor=north west] {\colorbox{white}{$\alpha=360$}};
    \draw [->,line width=1.5pt](0.5,0) arc (0:360:0.5cm);

    \end{animateinline}
    \end{center}

    \end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! In order to mark code as code, just put it in the selection and press the `{}` button while editing your question. (I did that here, but this is to explain what happened.) More importantly, your code does not compile for me because I do not have the file `time2.txt`. To hide some part, you can just put it into `\begin{scope}[opacity=0] ... \end{scope}`.

Answer (score 4):

Just put the original, black triangle on an animation *transparency* of its own. Then, use it in the first and last animation *frames* according to the timeline file `time.txt` listed below. Also note that the final triangle rotated by 360° was removed from the last transparency.

- Six animation "*transparencies*" 0 through 5:
  [image]
- Five animation *frames* 0 through 4, assembled from *transparencies* according to the timeline file

```
\begin{filecontents}{time.txt}
  ::0x0, 1 % axes+grid, black triangle
  ::2
  ::3
  ::4
  ::5, 1 % black triangle re-used
\end{filecontents}
```

[image]

Complete example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usepackage{color}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{time.txt}
  ::0x0, 1 % axes+grid, black triangle
  ::2
  ::3
  ::4
  ::5, 1 % black triangle re-used
\end{filecontents}    

\begin{document}

\begin{center}

\begin{animateinline}[
  begin={%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm]
    \clip(-4.7,-3.7)  rectangle (4.7,3.7);
  },
  end={\end{tikzpicture}},
  controls,
  timeline=time.txt
]{1}
  % axes + grid
  \draw [color=gray] (-4.5,-3.2) grid (4.5,3.2);

  \foreach \x in {-4,...,4}
  \draw [very thick] (\x,0.1) -- (\x,-0.1) node[below] {\x};
  \foreach \y in {-3,...,3}
  \draw [very thick] (0.1,\y) -- (-0.1,\y) node[left] {\y};

  \draw [<->, very thick] (-4.5,0) -- (4.5,0) node [below] {$x$};
  \draw [<->, very thick] (0,-3.5) -- (0,3.5) node [right] {$y$};

\newframe % starting triangle
  \draw [line width=1.5pt] (0,1) -- (1,3) -- (3,1) -- cycle;

\newframe % GIRO 90°
  \draw [color=blue,line width=1.5pt] (-1,0) -- (-3,1) -- (-1,3)-- cycle;
  \draw[color=black] (3.,2.7) node[anchor=north west] {\colorbox{white}{$\alpha=90$}};
  \draw [->,line width=1.5pt](0.5,0) arc (0:90:0.5cm);

\newframe % GIRO 180°
  \draw [color=blue,line width=1.5pt] (0,-1) -- (-1,-3) -- (-3,-1)-- cycle;
  \draw[color=black] (3.,2.7) node[anchor=north west] {\colorbox{white}{$\alpha=180$}};
  \draw [->,line width=1.5pt](0.5,0) arc (0:180:0.5cm);

\newframe % GIRO 270°
  \draw [color=blue, line width=1.5pt] (1,0) -- (3,-1) -- (1,-3)-- cycle;
  \draw[color=black] (3.,2.7) node[anchor=north west] {\colorbox{white}{$\alpha=270$}};
  \draw [->,line width=1.5pt](0.5,0) arc (0:270:0.5cm);

\newframe % GIRO 360°, last transparency without triangle
  \draw[color=black] (3.,2.7) node[anchor=north west] {\colorbox{white}{$\alpha=360$}};
  \draw [->,line width=1.5pt](0.5,0) arc (0:360:0.5cm);

\end{animateinline}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much AlexG, your help was of great importance. I share my design.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usepackage{color}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\newcommand{\grad}{^{\circ}} 



\begin{filecontents}{time.txt}
  ::0x0 
  ::1
  ::2
  ::3
  ::4 
\end{filecontents}    

\begin{document}

\begin{animateinline}[
  begin={%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm]
    \clip(-4.7,-3.7)  rectangle (4.8,3.7);
  },
  end={\end{tikzpicture}},
  controls,
  timeline=time.txt
]{1}
  % axes + grid
  \draw [color=gray] (-4.5,-3.2) grid (4.5,3.2);

  \foreach \x in {-4,...,4}
  \draw [very thick] (\x,0.1) -- (\x,-0.1) node[below] {\x};
  \foreach \y in {-3,...,3}
  \draw [very thick] (0.1,\y) -- (-0.1,\y) node[left] {\y};

  \draw [<->, very thick] (-4.5,0) -- (4.5,0) node [below] {$x$};
  \draw [<->, very thick] (0,-3.5) -- (0,3.5) node [right] {$y$};

  \draw [line width=1.5pt] (0,1) -- (1,3) -- (3,1) -- cycle;

    \begin{scriptsize}
        \draw[color=black] (0.2,0.7) node {{\large $A$}};
        \draw[color=black] (3.2,0.7) node {{\large$B$}};
        \draw[color=black] (1.5,3) node {{\large$C$}};
    \end{scriptsize}

\newframe % GIRO 90°
  \draw [color=blue,line width=1.5pt] (-1,0) -- (-3,1) -- (-1,3)-- cycle;
  \draw[color=black] (2.9,2.7) node[anchor=north west] {\colorbox{white}{$\alpha=90 \grad $}};
  \draw [->,color=green, line width=1.5pt](0.5,0) arc (0:90:0.5cm);

    \begin{scriptsize}
    \draw[color=black] (-0.7,0.3) node {{\large $A'$}};
    \draw[color=black] (-0.7,3.2) node {{\large$B'$}};
    \draw[color=black] (-3,1.5) node {{\large$C'$}};
  \end{scriptsize}

\newframe % GIRO 180°
  \draw [color=blue,line width=1.5pt] (0,-1) -- (-1,-3) -- (-3,-1)-- cycle;
  \draw[color=black] (2.9,2.7) node[anchor=north west] {\colorbox{white}{$\alpha=180 \grad $}};
  \draw [->,color=green, line width=1.5pt](0.5,0) arc (0:180:0.5cm);

    \begin{scriptsize}
    \draw[color=black] (-0.3,-0.7) node {{\large $A'$}};
    \draw[color=black] (-3.2,-0.7) node {{\large$B'$}};
    \draw[color=black] (-1.5,-3) node {{\large$C'$}};
  \end{scriptsize}

\newframe % GIRO 270°
  \draw [color=blue, line width=1.5pt] (1,0) -- (3,-1) -- (1,-3)-- cycle;
  \draw[color=black] (2.9,2.7) node[anchor=north west] {\colorbox{white}{$\alpha=270 \grad $}};
  \draw [->,color=green, line width=1.5pt](0.5,0) arc (0:270:0.5cm);

        \begin{scriptsize}
    \draw[color=black] (0.7,-0.2) node {{\large $A'$}};
    \draw[color=black] (0.7,-3.2) node {{\large$B'$}};
    \draw[color=black] (3,-1.5) node {{\large$C'$}};
  \end{scriptsize}

\newframe % GIRO 360°
  \draw [color=blue, line width=1.5pt] (0,1) -- (1,3) -- (3,1) -- cycle;
  \draw[color=black] (2.9,2.7) node[anchor=north west] {\colorbox{white}{$\alpha=360 \grad $}};
  \draw [->,color=green, line width=1.5pt](0.5,0) arc (0:360:0.5cm);

\end{animateinline}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If @AlexG's response has solved your problem, it is customary to accept it, read: https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers